# Custom JSON file doesn't work with Highcharts

Tags: json, highcharts

I'm very new to HighCharts and have a question about integrating JSON files.

I'm attempting to call a JSON file for my HighCharts file, however when I attempt to call it, the chart breaks and nothing is displayed. I am using the [base Highcharts code](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.9.1/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/stock/demo/basic-line/) in order to do this.

Here is my JSON input file that I am trying to use:

```
[
    [Date.UTC(2012,00,01),2],
    [Date.UTC(2012,00,02),6],
    [Date.UTC(2012,00,03),4],
    [Date.UTC(2012,00,04),0],
    [Date.UTC(2012,00,05),2],
    [Date.UTC(2012,00,06),3],
    [Date.UTC(2012,00,07),1],
    [Date.UTC(2012,00,08),3],
    [Date.UTC(2012,00,09),7],
    [Date.UTC(2012,00,10),8]
]
```

I have found other examples which say that it would be better to create an array with the data in it and put it into the JS file, and while that may work now it won't be feasible in the future as the chart will eventually have to reference large JSON files that will be stored in another directory.

Here's a link to the [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jdeheus/2kGyf/2/) that references the outside JSON file. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: If that's a "JSON input file" (rather than just a JavaScript data-structure in the browser) then it's invalid JSON.

Comment: Just to make it more clear: JSON doesn't allow functions like `Date.UTC()`, instead there should be timestamp, for example: `Date.UTC(2012,00,10)` -> `1326153600000`.